# Displaying virtualenv

Tags: python, shell, virtualenv

When I am in my virtualenv and it's active, the name of the environment appears in parentheses before the normal command line prompt. It looks like: `(foo-env)User:~/Development/foo-env/foo$` where `foo-env` is the name of the environment. I was wondering if there was a way to make it that the command line prompt displayed something like `(F)User:~/Development/foo-env/foo$` as opposed to the current display with `(foo-env)`. If this is possible how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 6):

So I figured out how to do this. In the activate script the `$PS1` is redefined to prepend the name of the env, in this case `(foo-env)`. In order to prepend it with whatever you want you have to go into the `activate` script that you run to activate the `virtualenv` (`[yourenv]/bin/activate]`). There you change the line that that defines the new `$PS1` from `` PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`)$PS1" `` to be whatever you want, here `PS1="(F)$PS1"`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the $PS1 environmental variable to change your prompt.

Take a look in the virtualenv config files for the setting.

See http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html for how to set it as you'd like. It sounds like you just need to replace the string `foo-env` with `F`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, use [pew](https://github.com/berdario/pew) (Python Env Wrapper). Then your `PS1` won't get mangled when you use a virtualenv, and you can set your `PS1` in your `.bashrc` (etc.) as usual, displaying the `$VIRTUAL_ENV` if it's set. The relevant piece of [mine](https://github.com/ajschumacher/.emacs.d/blob/master/bash/.bashrc) looks like this:

```
# python virtual env, however it comes to be
if [ -z ${VIRTUAL_ENV+x} ]
then
VENV_NOTICE=""
else
VENV_NOTICE=" (py: $(basename "$VIRTUAL_ENV"))"
fi

PS1='whatever $VENV_NOTICE else'
```